# DexArchiveBuilderException exception when using stanford corenlp

Tags: java, android, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I am trying to do Lemmatization on words using [stanford corenlp](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) But when I added there dependency as below.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 27



defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}


 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
compile 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
compile 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.8.0'

 }
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

When I run my app it gives me following exception:

> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\LPT-0096.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\edu.stanford.nlp\stanford-corenlp\3.8.0\79c0ba8dba9734bf51d898f4526117980f7c49c5\stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar
>   Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotator.unmount()
>    Error:com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotator.unmount()
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':ModroidApp:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\LPT-0096.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\edu.stanford.nlp\stanford-corenlp\3.8.0\79c0ba8dba9734bf51d898f4526117980f7c49c5\stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar

Please help me why I am getting following exception whenever I run my application.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace output :

> com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Default interface
>   methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24)

<s>So you have to ugrade your `minSdkVersion` to 24</s>

**EDIT:**
[Enabling java 8 compatibiliy](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) solve the issue : adding the block below to `build.gradle`

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I went in deep understood why its require minimum **v24** . Reason being it only allow **v24** and above is that it uses **java 1.8** which are only supported in **v24** and higher version i believe.

So i changed **compile 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.8.0'**
 to **compile 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.4.1'** and it worked for me for more details you can read [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html)